# Java PDFBox - Change attachment font

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a service that attaches files to pdf, and a requirement to support attaching files with name in Thai alphabet. However, I get a strange name in the attached file when doing so:

[image]

this is done using `fs.setFileUnicode()`. using `fs.setFile()` generates an even stranger name:

[image]

How can I preserve the Thai file name?

Comment: @mkl pinging you for your experience with pdfbox

Comment: Please post a sample PDF file for investigation

Comment: Indeed, please share a sample PDF. Also tell us the Adobe Acrobat Reader version you use.

Comment: Do you have the asian fonts package in your Adobe Reader? https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/font-pack-spelling-dictionary-64-bit-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using both `fs.setFile()` and `fs.setFileUnicode()`, plus `fs.setEmbeddedFile()`